Heat & Glo conversion kit
I'm looking to convert my heat & glo fireplace from propane to natural gas,the discontinued conversion kit is #NGK-6GLX-IPI... availability?

Discontinued means generally low availability. Check with a Heat & Glo dealer (or two) near you.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a shopping question.
